# Why can't using double quotes in awk?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I tried set separator `-F:` in here.

```
awk -F "{print $1}" /etc/passwd
```

But its not effects...

Then I found out use `'{…}'` instead of `"{…}'`. It's works good!

So what's difference in `'{…}'` and `"{…}"` for `awk`? Thank you!!

Comment: Your command line is missing the `:` — which leads to problems.  Use `awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd`.  With double quotes around the script, the `$1` is expanded — to nothing — so the `print` prints the whole line.  Use single quotes around `awk` scripts on the command line unless you're confident in handling the difference between single and double quotes in the shell.

Comment: It's not awk that has a distinction between quote types, it's bash.

Comment: Emmm... I forgot type a : about opt of -F. Sorry